# Possible omission of a relative pronoun in the beginning of a clause?

Tags: pronoun, typo

I have been reading an article in the news, and could not understand the following sentence.

> Vielmehr fehlt das politische Motiv, ein geopolitischer Wettkampf der
>   Systeme wie einst bei Apollo, oder ein zwingendes Geschäftsmodell, **mit
>   sich** der Einsatz so vieler Steuergelder als gewinnbringende
>   Investition rechtfertigen ließe.

Isnt there missing `dem` after `mit` in last subordinate clause? I mean `dem` in a sense of dative of `das`, a relative pronoun for `Motiv`.

If not, could you please describe what happens in the last clause?

Comment: Yes, either mit dem or womit.

Comment: @user30167 On the plus side, you can congratulate yourself on successfully guessing the wright solution for this cloze test of sorts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, there should be „**mit dem**“. It's just German journalismus A.D. 2019 at its finest. In most media assets, even in largest such as der „Spiegel“, nobody ever cares to proofread articles. Sometimes one sees such weird typos, misspellings etc. that one would think not even the author had proofread their masterpiece.

Comment: Of cause nobody proofreads any more. Proofreading is time-consuming, and human working time is expensive. **And since everything is written on text editors with a spell-check-function, proofreading by humans is not necessary any more** (there might be some sarcasm in the bold part)

Comment: BTW, proofreading by the author - although better than no proofreading at all - is significantly less efficient than proofreading by someone else. As the author you remember your thoughts and intentions, so half the time you'll read what you *wanted* to write instead of what you *actually did* write.

Comment: I suspect that texts for print are occasionally shortened to fit the collumn constraints vs acceptable Textbild (whitespace distribution, avoidance of bad line breaks, Hurenkinder etc) at the cost of good orthography. I do so for space constrained internet comments at least. I don't know whether the cited piece was print first or word count constrained. An honest error is a real possibility, but such glaring omissions make one wonder for sure.

Comment: @VolkerLandgraf "of cause" -- I see what you did there. Par for course, quid pro quo :)

Comment: @vectory Ich benutze auch gerne mal den Begriff "T**u**ppfehler" um auf ebensolche hinzuweisen ;-)

Comment: -1 while the first part is correct, the rest is nothing more than a rant.

Comment: @mtwde thanks for your opinion. I don't think this was "nothing but a rant" because that was actually the explanation of a **very** widespread phenomenenon

Comment: @vectory, I think that would be overcomplicating things :) For on numerous occasions I saw things like multiple "habe" in the same sentence, one placed correctly and one being a leftover from the former word order, or just typed in twice by mistake.

Comment: @Dan I see what you did there and why you did it :) . But parts like "nobody ever cares" & terms like "masterpiece" are imho unnecessary exaggerations.